# Not able to update the artifact properties using jfrog-cli command line

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

We are using `jfrog-cli` to upload the build artifact to Artifactory.

Once it's uploaded, I would like to add/update the build artifact properties.

I'm using following command:

```
jfrog rt sp "<artifactory_server>/<repo>/<version>/*.zip" "Build1=test1"
```

It returns as follows:

```
[Debug] Artifactory response:  200 OK
[Info] Setting properties...
[Info] Done setting properties.
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: try removing the <artifactory_server>

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you added your artifactory_server to the path.
You should run the following instead:

```
jfrog rt sp "<repo>/<version>/*.zip" "Build1=test1"
```

In addition, if you manage several Artifactory instances through JFrog CLI you could point to the specific Artifactory instance by using the `--server-id` flag as the following:

```
jfrog rt sp "<repo>/<version>/*.zip" "Build1=test1" --server-id=my_artifactory
```